# What does the PHP manual mean by "Process IDs are not unique"? How do I get the actual unique "process id"?

Tags: php, process, windows-10, pid

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php

> Warning ***Process IDs are not unique***, thus they are a weak entropy source. We recommend against relying on pids in security-dependent contexts.

How can a "process id" not be unique? What am I missing? And `getmyuid()` is equally nonsensical in that it doesn't give any useful process id back, but only:

> Gets PHP script owner's UID

In short: How do I get some kind of ***unique id*** for the current (CLI) PHP process from where this is run?

Comment: For what purpose? http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: It's telling you not to use it for adding randomness to something.  If you need the PID use the PID.

Comment: Process management, naturally.

Comment: ok well then it's not a problem for you. By "not unique" it means "not unique forever", i.e. when a process ends, the operating system can re-use the same ID to number a newly created process. Notice how the text you quoted says not to rely on it in "security-dependent contexts". i.e. not as a random salt for encryption and suchlike.

Answer (score 1):

PIDs are not unique. If a process dies the OS may reuse the ID for a new one. This is not a PHP thing.

If you want to generate unique values use `uniqid()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

If you're on linux you could also use `uuidgen`in backtics (``):

```
var_dump(`uuidgen`);
```